# Can I always use this.props to call a function from the actions?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm doing a Redux tutorial, and don't understand something in it. I have the following container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CommentsList from "./comments_list";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class CommentBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { comment: '' };
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ comment: event.target.value })
    }

    submitButton(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.saveComment(this.state.comment);
        this.setState({ comment: '' });
    }

    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.submitButton(e)} className="comment-box">
                    <textarea
                        value={this.state.comment}
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
                    <button action="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <CommentsList comment={this.state.comment}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(CommentBox);
```

This container uses:

```
import * as actions from '../actions';
```

and on the bottom of the file:

```
export default connect(null, actions)(CommentBox);
```

I'm used to using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps, but here only the actions are imported, and then used in the submitButton(e) method:

```
this.props.saveComment(this.state.comment);
```

The saveComment comes from the actions/index.js file:

```
import { SAVE_COMMENT } from './types';

export function saveComment(comment) {
    return {
        type: SAVE_COMMENT,
        payload: comment
    }
}
```

**Can I always use this.props to call a function from the actions/index.js file? Why don't I need to use the mapStateToProps first?**

Comment: I think there's an error in this example, your `saveComment` function is not dispatched. Is it intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I always use this.props to call a function from the actions/index.js file?

Yes.  From the [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> `[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps]` (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

`connect` is wrapping the exports from `actions/index.js` with `dispatch` calls for you.

---

> Why don't I need to use the mapStateToProps first?

Because `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are used for different purposes and mapped separately before being merged together and injected into your component.

If either return `undefined` or `null`, they are ignored.  In the case of `mapStateToProps`, it also means the component won't subscribe to updates from the store. Again, from the [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> If you don't want to subscribe to store updates, pass null or undefined in place of mapStateToProps.